# TypeScript After setup innerHTML in class method parent class make constronted again

Tags: typescript

Explanation : 
I have class ConnectorClient :

```
class ConnectorClient {

  private webSocketController;
  private popupForm: HTMLDivElement;

  constructor(config: EngineConfig) {

    this.popupForm = byId("popup") as HTMLDivElement;

    this.webSocketController = new WebSocket(config.getRemoteServerAddressControlller());
    this.webSocketController.onopen = this.onOpen;
    this.webSocketController.onclose = this.onClose;
    this.webSocketController.onmessage = this.onMessage;
    this.webSocketController.onerror = this.onError;

    // window.WWW = this;
    this.showRegisterForm();

  }
 public showRegisterForm() {

    const myInstance = this;
    fetch("./templates/register.html", {
      headers: htmlHeader,
    }).
      then(function (res) {
        return res.text();
      }).then(function (html) {
        // console.warn(html);
        myInstance.popupForm.innerHTML = html;
        byId("login-button").addEventListener("click", myInstance.registerUser, false);
        byId("forgotPassword").addEventListener("click", myInstance.ForgotPassword, false);
      });

  }

  public registerUser = (e) => {

    const localEmail: string = (byId("login-user") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    const localPassword: string = (byId("login-pass") as HTMLInputElement).value;

    if (validateEmail(localEmail) !== null) {
      byId("error-msg-reg").style.display = "block";
      byId("error-msg-reg").innerText = validateEmail(localEmail);
    }

    if (validatePassword(localPassword) === false) {
      byId("error-msg-reg").style.display = "block";
      byId("error-msg-reg").innerText += "Password is not valid! length!";
    }

    if (validateEmail(localEmail) === null && validatePassword(localPassword) === true) {

      const userData: IUserRegData = {
        email: localEmail,
        password: localPassword,
      };

      let localMsg = { data: { action: "REGISTER", userRegData: userData } };
      this.sendObject(localMsg);
      localMsg = null;

    }

  }
```

In any situation when i call this method class i get loaded again with error on getElementById etc..!

What to do ?

Too see full code look at : 
[Opensource project:visual ts game engine](https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/visual-ts-game-engie/tree/master/src/libs/class/networking)

Strange is change on page url in: app.html?

Char ? is come from nowhere!

Comment: A bit more code is needed here. Even better: "working" http://jsfiddle.net/, http://plnkr.co/. Where do you call getElementById? Where do you set `this.popupForm`?

Comment: I fixed this part with fetch call but program broke in next innerHTML line... For example ...